# Why is the ring $\mathbb{Z}[2\sqrt{2}]$ not a unique factorization domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

> Why is the polynomial ring $R[x]$ not a unique factorization domain, where $R$ is the quadratic integer ring $\mathbb{Z}[2\sqrt{2}]$?

I'm trying to find an irreducible non-prime element or something but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 6):

It is enough to show that $\mathbb{Z}[2\sqrt{2}]$ is not a unique factorisation domain (why?).

The elements $2$ and $2\sqrt{2}$ are irreducible and
$$
8 = (2\sqrt{2})^2 = 2^3,
$$
so the factorisation is not unique.

Comment: How would one show that those two elements are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[2\sqrt{2}]$?

Comment: Try to solve $2= ab$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}[2\sqrt{2}]$. You should use that $\sqrt{2}$ and $1$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Do the same for $2\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $ $ Over $\, R = \Bbb Z[w],\ w =2\sqrt{2},\,$ the *proper* fraction $\,w/2\,$ is a root of *monic* $\,x^2-2,\,$ contra the Rational Root Test (which [is true in any UFD;](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4343557/242) i.e. UFDs are *integrally closed*).

Comment: Nice answer! Do you know what we can tell about $R[x]$ (is it a UFD), as asked in the question?

Comment: @Watson $\ R\,$ not integrally closed $\,\Rightarrow R\,$ not UFD $\,\Rightarrow\, R[x]$ not UFD $\ $