# Deducing that $\mathbb Z[2 \sqrt{2}]$ is not a $UFD.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, unique-factorization-domains, fraction-field

Here is the question I am trying to understand the solution of the last part in it:

Let $R$ be an integral domain with quotient field $F$ and let $p(x)$ be a monic polynomial in $R[x].$ Assume that $p(x) = a(x) b(x)$ where $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are monic polynomials in $F[x]$ of smaller degree than $p(x).$ Prove that if $a(x) \notin R[x]$ then $R$ is not a $UFD$. Deduce that $\mathbb Z[2 \sqrt{2}]$ is not a $UFD$.

Here is a solution I found here:

[$\mathbb{Z}[2\sqrt2]$ is not a UFD.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3927160/mathbbz2-sqrt2-is-not-a-ufd)

**My question is:**

What is the quotient field of $\mathbb Z[2 \sqrt{2}][x]$? Why the given factors in the solution are in the quotient field of $\mathbb Z[2 \sqrt{2}][x]$?

Can someone clarify this to me please?

Comment: The quotient field of $R:=\mathbb Z[2 \sqrt{2}]$ is [$F:=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension#Examples).

The quotient field of $R[x]$ is therefore $F(x)$ but this is off topic.

The ["given](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3927249) factors" $a(x)=b(x)=x+\sqrt 2$ are clearly in $F[x]$ (but not in $R[x]$).

Comment: You don't want the quotient field of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}][x]$. You want the polynomials with coefficients in the quotient field of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ (which is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin why you are saying this ? Why $\mathbb Z[ \sqrt{2} ]$ and not $\mathbb Z[ 2\sqrt{2} ],$ I do not understand you, could you please explain this?

Comment: @AnneBauval  why you are saying this ? Why $\mathbb Q[ \sqrt{2} ]$ and not $\mathbb Q[ 2\sqrt{2} ]$ is the quotient field? I do not understand you, could you please explain this?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a couple of $2$s; but the point is that you are asking for the quotient field of the **polynomial ring**  $\mathbb{Z}[2\sqrt{2}][x]$; but what you want is the *polynomial ring over the quotient field* of $\mathbb{Z}[2\sqrt{2}]$; that one is exactly the same as the quotient field of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, namely $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]=\mathbb{Q}[2\sqrt{2}]=\mathbb{Q}(2\sqrt{2})$.  That is, you want the polynomial ring over the quotient field, not the quotient field *of* the polynomial ring.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[2\sqrt{2}]=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$. You clearly have $\subseteq$, and $\sqrt{2}=\frac{1}{2}(2\sqrt{2})\in\mathbb{Q}[2\sqrt{2}]$, giving $\supseteq$.